# Quicksort em ordem crescente em Python

Tags: python

Preciso ordenar a quantidade de vezes que as  palavras se repetem no arquivo txt, mas sempre que rodo o código ele printa em ordem decrescente.

Código abaixo:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('/Users/DIGITAL/Desktop/Python/teste.txt') as f:
    ocorrencias = Counter(f.read().split())
print(ocorrencias)

def quicksort(ocorrencias):
    if len (lista) <= 1:
        return lista
    pivo = lista[0]
    iguais = [x for x in lista if x == pivo]
    menores =[ x for x in lista if x < pivo]
    maiores = [x for x in lista if x > pivo]
    return quicksort(menores)+iguais+quicksort(maiores)
    print(quicksort(ocorrencias))
```

Comment: Precisa obrigatoriamente ser Quicksort?

Ou você simplesmente quer quanto cada palavra aparece? Se for existe um meio melhor de resolver.

Comment: Tem que ser Quicksort. Eu já consegui contar a quantidade de repetições, mas o programa printa em ordem decrescente. Preciso que ele printe em ordem crescente.

Comment: Você está guardando tudo em uma lista?

Comment: Não. Tá num arquivo txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dicionários não possuem ordenação](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-to-sort-a-dictionary-by-value). A função `collections.Counter()` retorna um dicionário.

O segredo para se ordenar dicionarios está em convertê-los para uma lista de tuplas para então ordená-las.

Com uma pequena modificação na função de *quicksort* da sua pergunta, é possível trabalhar com a ordenação de uma lista de tuplas e parametrizar em qual ordem vai ocorrer o ordenamento da lista:

```
from collections import Counter

def quicksort( array, reverse=False ):
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array
    ( _, pv ) = array[0]
    iguais = [ (k,v) for k,v in array if v == pv ]
    maiores = quicksort([ (k,v) for k,v in array if v > pv ],reverse)
    menores = quicksort([ (k,v) for k,v in array if v < pv ],reverse)
    if reverse == True:
        return maiores + iguais + menores
    else:
        return menores + iguais + maiores


def ordenar( dic, reverse=False ):
    return quicksort( [ (k,v) for k,v in dic.items() ], reverse );


with open('teste.txt') as f:
    palavras = Counter( f.read().split() )

print "Crescente:", ordenar( palavras, reverse=False )
print "Decrescente:", ordenar( palavras, reverse=True )
```

**teste.txt**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

**Saída:**

```
Crescente: [('laborum.', 1), ('ad', 1), ('irure', 1), ('ea', 1), ('officia', 1),
            ('sunt', 1), ('eu', 1), ('sed', 1), ('elit,', 1), ('enim', 1),
            ('Duis', 1), ('et', 1), ('aliqua.', 1), ('labore', 1), ('incididunt', 1),
            ('reprehenderit', 1), ('est', 1), ('quis', 1), ('sit', 1),
            ('veniam,', 1), ('nostrud', 1), ('qui', 1), ('id', 1),
            ('consectetur', 1), ('aute', 1), ('consequat.', 1), ('mollit', 1),
            ('aliquip', 1), ('nulla', 1), ('Lorem', 1), ('do', 1), ('non', 1),
            ('commodo', 1), ('Ut', 1), ('sint', 1), ('velit', 1), ('cillum', 1),
            ('pariatur.', 1), ('ex', 1), ('esse', 1), ('proident,', 1), ('magna', 1),
            ('cupidatat', 1), ('ullamco', 1), ('deserunt', 1), ('ipsum', 1),
            ('amet,', 1), ('nisi', 1), ('fugiat', 1), ('occaecat', 1), ('minim', 1),
            ('culpa', 1), ('tempor', 1), ('laboris', 1), ('anim', 1),
            ('adipiscing', 1), ('Excepteur', 1), ('voluptate', 1), ('exercitation', 1),
            ('eiusmod', 1), ('dolore', 2), ('ut', 2), ('dolor', 2), ('in', 3)]

Decrescente: [('in', 3), ('dolore', 2), ('ut', 2), ('dolor', 2), ('laborum.', 1),
              ('ad', 1), ('irure', 1), ('ea', 1), ('officia', 1), ('sunt', 1),
              ('eu', 1), ('sed', 1), ('elit,', 1), ('enim', 1), ('Duis', 1),
              ('et', 1), ('aliqua.', 1), ('labore', 1), ('incididunt', 1),
              ('reprehenderit', 1), ('est', 1), ('quis', 1), ('sit', 1),
              ('veniam,', 1), ('nostrud', 1), ('qui', 1), ('id', 1),
              ('consectetur', 1), ('aute', 1), ('consequat.', 1), ('mollit', 1),
              ('aliquip', 1), ('nulla', 1), ('Lorem', 1), ('do', 1), ('non', 1),
              ('commodo', 1), ('Ut', 1), ('sint', 1), ('velit', 1), ('cillum', 1),
              ('pariatur.', 1), ('ex', 1), ('esse', 1), ('proident,', 1),
              ('magna', 1), ('cupidatat', 1), ('ullamco', 1), ('deserunt', 1),
              ('ipsum', 1), ('amet,', 1), ('nisi', 1), ('fugiat', 1), ('occaecat', 1),
              ('minim', 1), ('culpa', 1), ('tempor', 1), ('laboris', 1), ('anim', 1),
              ('adipiscing', 1), ('Excepteur', 1), ('voluptate', 1), ('exercitation', 1),
              ('eiusmod', 1)]
```